# power sum divisible by prime

Tags: number-theory

$p>2$ is a prime and $p-1$ doesn't divide $n$. Prove that
$$1^n+2^n+3^n+\ldots +(p-1)^n \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$

My solution so far: If $n$ is odd then 
\begin{align*}
1^n+2^n+3^n+\ldots +(p-1)^n &\equiv 1^n+2^n+3^n+\ldots +(-3)^n+(-2)^n+(-1)^n \\
&\equiv 1^n-1^n+2^n-2^n+\ldots +\left( \frac{p-1}2 \right)^n- \left( \frac{p-1}2 \right)^n\\
&\equiv 0
\end{align*}

How should I approach this problem, if $n$ is even?

Comment: Why did you delete your [prior question?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1244172/242)

Answer (score 2):

For the values of $n$ such that $p-1$ does not divide $n$, we use the concept of a primitive root modulo $p$.  This is an integer between $1$ and $p – 1$ whose powers, taken $\mod p$, produce a rearrangement of the integers from $1$ to $p – 1$. If you know finite field theory, it might be familiar.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n

Every prime number $p$ has at least one primitive root modulo $p$, $m$. So we rewrite the sum as:

$$m^n + (m^2)^n + ... +(m^{p-1})^n = m^n + (m^n)^2 + ... +  (m^n)^{p-1} = m^n \frac{(m^n)^{p-1}-1}{m^n-1}$$

Because $n$ is not a multiple of $p – 1$, the denominator is not zero (this is by group theory, the order of the multipicative group of integers modulo $p$ is $p-1$, so since $n$ is not a multiple of $p-1$, $m^n$ cannot be $1$ the identity of that group), while $m^n$ is within the multiplicative group of integers modulo $p$, so not divisible by $p$, hence when raised to $p-1$, it is equivalent to $1 \pmod p$ by Fermat's Little Theorem. So the numerator is $0$.

Comment: My mistake. I replaced the $+$ with $-$.

Comment: @okay edited with a proof. I hope you know some finite field theory, or at least some group theory! Try reading the page, basically the main fact we need is that the multiplicative group of integers modulo $p$ is cyclic.